# how to set property of JSON in data-atrribute (HTML5)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, custom-data-attribute

I have the following element:

```
<div id="car" data-details='{ "color":"blue", "price":2000" }'></div>
```

I would like to change the property "price" using jQuery or JS:

Please check out this JSfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mLuz9/

I've tried:

```
$("#car").attr("data-details", '{"color" : "red", "price": 5000}');
```

but this requires the "color" to  be set at the same time, I only want to set the "price" property.

Comment: You could make two data attributes one for color and one for price.

Comment: Get the attribute value, parse the value, update the `price` property of the object, stringify it to JSON and set the attribute of the element. If you thought that there is a more direct way, there isn't.

Comment: Thanks, can you update my JSfiddle so I can see how you did it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull your JSON out of the data attribute to a variable, edit the variable, and re-set the attribute with your the updated variable.

Something like this should work:

```
<div id="car" data-details='{ "color":"blue", "price":2000 }'></div>

// Pull the info from the data-details attribute into a variable called 'details'
var details = JSON.parse($('#car').attr('data-details'));

// Change the price property in our variable
details.price = 5000;

// Write the variable version of details back to the data-details
// attribute on the DOM element
$('#car').attr('data-details', JSON.stringify(details));

$("html").append($("#car").attr("data-details"));
```

An updated version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mLuz9/3/

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't seem to work. Check my JSfidle to see.

Comment: `.data` only updates the internal jQuery storage, not the attribute of the element.

Comment: 1. You have a syntax error in your JSON string that is in the data-details attribute.
2. I assumed you pasted all your code into the question and didn't look at your fiddle. I'll update my response

Comment: I fixed the syntax error, still can't figure how to set the property?

Comment: Added some comments, hope that helps

Comment: Thanks greg5green, that did the job, much appreciated.